# Is it possible to write R programs on Visual Studio 2022? And if yes, how to add it?

Tags: r, visual-studio-2022

It seems that Microsoft has removed R support from Visual Studio starting from the 2019 version.

I'm wondering if there's a way to write R code for Data Science on Visual Studio 2022 (Not VS Code) because I don't feel like using another IDE.

I've looked all over the internet and I could only find solutions for VS Code.

I've also seen some Microsoft documentation about it but I couldn't apply it.

Answer (score 4):

After long research, I have come to the conclusion that working with R on Visual Studio is ***no longer possible***.

One must use R Studio IDE instead, which also allows access to graphing tools and so on.

Comment: That was a huge missed opportunity by them. They had already done most of the work R is also increasingly being used in Web Apps, Frameworks like Shiny facilitate this. Azure Notebooks is not a replacement for Visual Studio. I mean VS2019 and the existing RTools are fine for not but I hope they change their minds in a future version.